# In Server Parsing Decimal gives wrong number

Tags: c#

In my application. I am parsing excel and in excel I am parcing a decimal number. I use OleDbConnection for parse excell. When I run on localhost parsing and converting to decimal is correct but in server it gives wrong numbers. It doesn't accept <,> seperator so numbers gives bigger.

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
conn.Open();
process = "Bağlantı açıldı";
var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();

    #region scope parse
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions()
    {
        IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(24000)
    }))
    {
        var context = new Entities2();
        // düzenle

        FNC_INVESTMENT_PERIOD_ACTUAL actual = new FNC_INVESTMENT_PERIOD_ACTUAL();
        decimal id = 0;
        List<FNC_INVESTMENT_PERIOD_ACTUAL> ActualDatas = new List<FNC_INVESTMENT_PERIOD_ACTUAL>();
        foreach (DataRow element in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            FNC_INVESTMENT_ACTUAL_DETAIL detail = new FNC_INVESTMENT_ACTUAL_DETAIL();
            string query = "select FNC_SEQ_ACTUAL_DETAIL.NEXTVAL from DUAL";
            var query_result = context.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(query);
            decimal newId = query_result.First();
            detail.ID = newId;
            detail.REFACTUALCODE = id;
            detail.DOCNO = element[1].ToString();
            detail.DOCDATE = Convert.ToDateTime(element[2]);
            detail.AMOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(element[4]);
            context.FNC_INVESTMENT_ACTUAL_DETAIL.Add(detail);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

1.547,07 this number returns 154707 so gives big number in server

How can I solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `element[4].GetType()`? `element[4].ToString()`?

Comment: Specify the [correct culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the culture:

Convert.ToDecimal(element[4].Replace('.', ' '), new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));

Please read this Microsoft document for more info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

u need to change the server Regional settings on the server machine
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989

Comment: That's not a good solution. If he deploys to a different machine, would end up with the same problem.